# Laravel Eloquent, group by month/year

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5, eloquent

i'm trying to group my data by month and year.

```
$data ->select(DB::raw('count(id) as `data`'),DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) year, MONTH(created_at) month'))
           ->groupby('year','month')
           ->get();
```

The output is :

```
{
"data": 19215,
"year": 2016,
"month": 10
},
```

if i group only by month, i don't know from which year belong this month, my expected output is :

```
{
"clicks": 19215,
"month": 11-2016,
},
{
"clicks": 11215,
"month": 12-2016,
},
```

i want to do it in sql, not in php.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can try as:

```
->select(DB::raw('count(id) as `data`'), DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m-%Y') new_date"),  DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) year, MONTH(created_at) month'))
->groupby('year','month')
->get();
```

Comment: QLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Comment: This is related to MySQL. Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/34115174/6040777

Comment: Not Mysql 5.7 compliant

Comment: The groupby will fail

Comment: I have already commented above it's related to MySQL check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql. And OP is already using `groupBY` in his query and he doesn't have any problem with that. It's totally off topic here to ask about MySQL compliant.

Comment: Wrong answer @AmitGupta

Comment: my query problem has been solved with that solution. Thanks

Answer (score 29):

**Note: This is solution based on eloquent, and yes, it not the best approach, but as the question is, this is using eloquent. If you want faster way, you can do it with raw query.**

If you want to group your results for example by year, you can use closure where you will parse your datetime to desired format (year or month).

Here is example of the code:

```
$res= ModelName::where('someColumn','test')
      ->get()
      ->groupBy(function($val) {
      return Carbon::parse($val->created_at)->format('Y');
});
```

Comment: This actually fetches every row from database into laravel and then does grouping in php. not recommendable approach.

Comment: This is solution based on eloquent, and yes, it not the best approach, but as the question is, this is using eloquent. If you want faster way, you can do it with raw query.

Comment: how to group by year and her months

Comment: @Brane how to group by year and her months, would we return this `Carbon::parse($val->created_at)->format('M-Y');` ??

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen from the documentation, the syntax is probably like this `->format('F Y');`

Comment: @Brane so then it would be `->format('Y-F');` for `2021-04` ?

Comment: Probably yes, I haven't test it.

Answer (score 20):

```
$result = ModelName::selectRaw('year(created_at) year, monthname(created_at) month, count(*) data')
                ->groupBy('year', 'month')
                ->orderBy('year', 'desc')
                ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case I wanted to order by month too. So my `select` became `monthname(created_at) month_name, month(created_at) month` and then `->groupBy('year', 'month', 'month_name')->orderBy('year', 'desc')->orderBy('month', 'desc')`.

Answer (score 7):

for latest version of mysql, the accepted answer will give error, so instead try

```
$data
    ->selectRaw("
        count(id) AS data, 
        DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m') AS new_date, 
        YEAR(created_at) AS year, 
        MONTH(created_at) AS month
    ")
    ->groupBy('new_date')
    ->get();
```

ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 2):

```
$data ->select(DB::raw('count(id) as `data`'),DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) year'),DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) month'))
       ->groupBy(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at)'), DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'))
       ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

[The answer by @Amit Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40529488/3001970) is a good, but it isn't working >= MySQL 5.7/MariaDB 10.2 and calls the error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

To solve that issue, you can use eg. [`MIN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_min) on the nonaggregated column:

```php
->select(
    DB::raw("
    count(id) as data, 
    MIN(DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m-%Y')) as new_date, 
    YEAR(created_at) year, 
    MONTH(created_at) month
    ")
)
->groupBy('year', 'month')
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

=>this might help someone in 2019

```
$date = "2019-06-16";

return date('m', strtotime($date)); //this return you 06(edited)
```

so you can do foreach by this method , so you don't need to do the all sql things..

Comment: did you mean 06?