# PHP Laravel extract data from db by month & year

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello i have this function which sums the budget_cost and get the data by month

```
public function marktingCost(){

$costs = \DB::table('campaigns')
    ->select('campaign_leadsource_id', \DB::raw('SUM(budget_cost) as budget_total_month'))
    ->addselect('campaign_leadsource_id', \DB::raw('SUM(budget_cost) as budget_total_year'))
    ->groupBy('campaign_leadsource_id')
    ->where('campaign_status_id',4) // campaign_status_id = 4 means campaign completed
    ->where(\DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'), Carbon::today()->month)
    ->get(); return $costs}
```

what im trying to achive is get the data by month as budget_total_month      and get the data by year as budget_total_year
but i can't use if condition inside query i want to do something like this

```
->select('campaign_leadsource_id', \DB::raw('SUM(budget_cost) as budget_total_month') ->where(\DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'), Carbon::today()->month))
->addselect('campaign_leadsource_id', \DB::raw('SUM(budget_cost) as budget_total_year') ->where(\DB::raw('Year(created_at)'), Carbon::today()->year))
```

But of course that's not valid

what i want as output is that

```
[{"campaign_leadsource_id":1,"budget_total_month":11475,"budget_total_year":134761,"olxTotal":12,"budget_per_lead":11230},{"campaign_leadsource_id":2,"budget_total_month":4221,"budget_total_year":41215,"olxTotal":9,"budget_per_lead":4579}]
```

thank you in advance

Comment: I'm assuming that the month one is meant to be the month from just one year rather than the same month from every year? What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: whereYear('created_at', '=', $year)
              ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', $month)

Comment: Hello Thank you for you answer i tried it like this 
`       ->select('campaign_leadsource_id', \DB::raw('SUM(budget_cost) as budget_total_' . $Month)->whereMonth('created_at', '=', $Month))
        ->addselect('campaign_leadsource_id', \DB::raw('SUM(budget_cost) as budget_total_' . $Year)->whereYear('created_at', '=', $year))`  
but i got "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression::whereMonth()"

Comment: im using laravel 5.7 just one month from this year

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code.

```
$costs = \DB::table('campaigns')
        ->select('campaign_leadsource_id', \DB::raw('SUM(budget_cost) as budget_total_month'))
        ->addselect('campaign_leadsource_id', \DB::raw('SUM(budget_cost) as budget_total_year'))

        ->where('campaign_status_id',4) // campaign_status_id = 4 means campaign completed
        ->where(\DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'), Carbon::today()->month)
        ->groupBy(\DB::raw("MONTH(created_at)"))
        ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer i tried it but got this error
`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'sedracrm.campaigns.campaign_leadsource_id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `campaign_leadsource_id`, SUM(budget_cost) as budget_total_month, `campaign_leadsource_id`, SUM(budget_cost) as budget_total_year from `campaigns` where `campaign_status_id` = 4 and MONTH(created_at) = 3 group by MONTH(created_at))`

Comment: Please do this. In config\database.php --> "mysql" array
Set 'strict' => false to disable all.

Or follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917189/laravel-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1055-error

Comment: It works but it get the data by month only and not by month & year

Comment: replace this `->groupBy(\DB::raw("MONTH(created_at)"),\DB::raw("YEAR(created_at)"))`  But you should check this to change the code in good shape https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529355/laravel-eloquent-group-by-month-year

Comment: it didn't work but thank you so much for your efforts <3

Comment: It should work, I have already done this before with the same approach. Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529355/laravel-eloquent-group-by-month-year

Answer (score 0):

I know you are using laravel classes/methods as an abstraction to SQL. But have you tried using PDO and actual SQL statements to retrieve the data?

Comment: i am totaly new how can i achieve that ? can you give me a code example to begin with ?

Comment: Sample PDO select statement can be seen at the bottom of this site https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp