# How to group records in year and month? laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have been already to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529355/laravel-eloquent-group-by-month-year) but its different in my case.

I have record which has a column `created_at`. My **objective** is to group the record by year, and inside each year, records should be group in month also.

My **expectations**:

[image]

---

I have tried this code below, but it is working only for yearly only.

```
$records = \App\VehicleRental::query()
    ->where('operator_id', $operator->id)
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function($val) { return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($val->created_at)->format('Y'); });
```

So I have tried to put another group for month but error *Property [created_at] does not exist on this collection instance.* returned

```
$record = \App\VehicleRental::query()
    ->where('operator_id', $operator->id)
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function($val) { return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($val->created_at)->format('M'); })
    ->groupBy(function($val) { return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($val->created_at)->format('Y'); });
```

---

Someone knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could also pass an array of elements to the [groupBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-groupby) collection method, for nested grouping. Try this:

```
$record = \App\VehicleRental::query()
    ->where('operator_id', $operator->id)
    ->get()
    ->groupBy([
        function ($val) { return $val->created_at->format('Y'); },
        function ($val) { return $val->created_at->format('m'); },
    ]);
```

---

As a side note, the `created_at` could be directly casted as a Carbon instance. If the above doesn't work, define the attribute [date mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) in your model:

```
# VehicleRental.php

protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
```

Comment: Sir the months are not sorted. No ideas how to append `->sortBy(created_at)` could you do me that favor

Comment: Then sort it first: `\App\VehicleRental::query()->orderBy('created_at')->where(...)->get()->[...]`

Comment: @charles you didn't mention any `log_in` in  your question. Update your post to see the logic in there.

Comment: it is `created_at` Sir. lots of tabs here sorry. by the I tried `->orderBy('created_at')
            ->get()
            ->groupBy(` but still months are not sorted. Only the year