# Group by month and years eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel

[image]

I want count passengers and the result group by month and year maybe like this (just an example), so what's query on laravel to call like this ?

```
{

2019 => [

January=>0,

Februari=>0,

March=>0,

April=>0,

May=>0,

June=>0,

July=>0,

August=>0,

September=>0,

October=>0,

November=>0,

December=>2,

],

2020 => [

January=>0,

Februari=>0,

March=>4,

April=>2,

May=>1,

June=>0,

July=>0,

August=>0,

September=>0,

October=>0,

November=>0,

December=>0,

],

}
```

but if that's not possible, I want to know the query to result group by month just in one year on laravel
thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
    $values=Passenger::select(DB::raw('count(name)',
DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m-%Y') new_date",
DB::raw('YEAR(date) year, MONTH(date) month'))
->groupby('year','month')->get();
```

please make sure that you table name is 'passengers' and your model name is Passenger

see :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3366929/10573560

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40529488/10573560

Comment: it says error like this Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  function year(date) does not exist.. I'm working with laravel

Comment: still error : Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "year"
LINE 1: ..., DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m-%Y') new_date, YEAR(date) year, MONT...