# Order by date in different columns in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I can't seem to get how to order by month in Laravel 7. I use different columns for my month, day, year and time and instead of ordering it by month, it orders the months alphabetically.

**Intended Result:** January, February, March, April 
**Actual Result:** April, February, January, March

This is my code:

```
$ledgers = Ledger::orderBy('month', 'DESC')
            ->orderBy('day', 'DESC')
            ->orderBy('year', 'DESC')
            ->orderBy('time', 'DESC')
            ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->paginate(8);
```

Comment: Well, if your `month` column is a `varchar` that contains the text of the month, of course it's going to order alphabetically... This seems like a pretty bad way to store dates. You should store a `date`, `datetime` or `timestamp`, and use functions like `DATE_FORMAT` to get the month, day, year, etc etc.

Comment: Is the month a number or a string? If it's a string you will have to build custom sort logic.  Is there a specific reason you don't use datetime instead of the separate columns?

Comment: It is a string. I'm still learning how to do backend and what my teacher told us to separate them. It was also easier to get the monthly and daily reports through it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all: i must say that you should store your date info in database in datetime column like Tim Lewis said in comment ...

any way
you can use order by fields , this kind of order make the result ordered according to the fields you provide ...

```
$ledgers = Ledger::orderByRaw('FIELD(month,'January','February','March','May', 'June','July','August','September','October','November','December')')
            ->orderBy('day', 'DESC')
            ->orderBy('year', 'DESC')
            ->orderBy('time', 'DESC')
            ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->paginate(8);
```

please see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9378709/10573560

Comment: Okay, if this doesn't work I'll probably try to convert everything to datetime. Can it be ordered desc? I tried adding `desc` but it doesn't work.

Comment: please see this, i have generic info about what you need:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40529488/10573560

Comment: if you want to sort desc using field way, you should reverse the field values:
December,November ... ex

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I can't seem to make groupBy working based from the references you gave so I just manually used `orderBy`

Comment: I'll accept this. Thank you so much for the help and time