# How to group retrieved rows by months?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I working on an app that involves grouping selected rows by month. How do I go about it?

```
  $data = Medicals::where("patient_referral.referred_by", "like", "%" .  $searchitem . "%")
        ->leftJoin("patients", "medicals.patients_id", "=", "patients.id")
        ->join("patient_referral", "medicals.trx_id", "=", "patient_referral.trx_id")
        ->join("tests", "medicals.tests_id", "=", "tests.id")
        ->groupBy(function (Medicals $item) {
            return $item->created_at->format('Y-m');
        })
        ->get();
```

This is the error am getting

ErrorException
stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: What is the problem you are having, does your query not work as you expect? You need to add some more information to your question. If you get an error, add it to your question.

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529355/laravel-eloquent-group-by-month-year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are calling `groupBy` is for Collections, not a query. You need to move that `groupBy` after the `get` so you are trying to group the resulting Collection.

```
    ...
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function ($item) {
        return $item->created_at->format('Y-m');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a raw query in a `groupBy` to execute it in the database:

```
$data = Medicals::where("patient_referral.referred_by", "like", "%" .  $searchitem . "%")
        ...
        ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(medicals.created_at, "%Y-%m")'))
        ->get();
```